# FCM Notification Images not seen for Inactive Users

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native

I have a React Native app configured with **Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)** push notifications. The notifications are configured in the Backend and are triggered based on some qualifying criteria.
The notifications work perfectly **fine** (with title, body, Images) for users who are **active**.
But for users who are **inactive**, the FCM notification **does not show image** of the notification rather only shows the title and body of the notification. Any thoughts?

Thanks for your support.

Comment: Are you use `@react-native-firebase/messaging` https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage ?

Comment: @VasylNahuliak   yes

Comment: What are you mean when said "inactive" and "active" user?

Comment: The users of the app, people who use the app frequently => active, people who registered but do not use the app => inactive

Comment: I guess Android in **inactive** users restrict push https://stackoverflow.com/a/66720434/10617148